# Find the rating that given to a certian game by each member who rated it in SQL

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE members
(
name        varchar(40),
ID          char(6)         PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE games
(
name        varchar(100),
ID      serial                  PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE ratings
(
memberID    char(6)            REFERENCES members(ID),
rating      SMALLINT CHECK(rating >= 1 AND rating <= 8),
gameID      integer            REFERENCES games(ID),
        PRIMARY KEY (memberID, gameID)
);
```

I am trying to find all the ratings that were given to the game that has an ID of (2) following by each member who rated it.

I used:

```
SELECT rating, name 
    FROM ratings, members 
    WHERE gameID = 2;
```

Whenever i used this command, it gives me the correct rating value but it lists all the members even if the member did not rate the game. Can someone help to figure out how to solve the problem.

thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
SELECT rating, name 
FROM ratings, members 
WHERE gameID = 2 and ratings.memberID = members.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `JOIN`:

```
SELECT rating, name 
FROM ratings r
     INNER JOIN members m
       ON r.MemberID = m.ID
WHERE gameID = 2;
```